Rust implementation of ChaCha20/Poly1305 or AES-GCM that uses GPU?
Do you know of any Rust implementation of ChaCha20/Poly1305 or AES-GCM that uses the GPU (especially CUDA) for encryption?

I don't see any reason to run cipher on GPU other than to play videos protected by DRM, even then, it's recommended to use the Vulkan API for protected memory.

@DannyNiu It could be relevant for password cracking with an algorithm like scrypt (if that used ChaCha instead) or something AES-based. However, I agree it's a weird question.

Even if there can be a Rust implementation of "cipher on GPU", to run code on them you still need to use languages such as GLSL, HLSL, to generate GPU-executed code. And these languages currently don't have features such as borrow checking, or other safety features (considering those languages're very limited in capability anyway).
